# Importing SWF File into Captivate

Tags: actionscript-3, import, flash, adobe-captivate

I have inserted a AS3 SWF (a Video Created in flash pro) into a slide in captivate. I have an audio that must synchronize with SWF in captivate. while I'm playing it in edit mode (in timeline) it works properly, but when I Publish it, SWF plays faster than audio.

I have tried inserting audio into Flash pro either. but when I insert it into captivate (in publish) SWF movie doesn't work very well( it has jump between Frames).
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: did you check the option "synchronize with project" on the swf properties ?

Comment: It wasn't checked. I checked it but still there is the problem.

Comment: Ok :/ if you embed a movie that have a lot of frames with audio, it happens sometimes that cp loose sync. The work arround I use is to create a simple widget that load & play the external SWF, pause the cp movie and navigates to the next cp slide when done.

Comment: Rafh Thank you for your help. The problem was in Captivate FPS, it was not matched with my SWF file. I changed it to 24 and now it works properly.